# How to run jasmine-node tests in the browser (ex. using testem)?

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine, jasmine-node, testem

How do I run jasmine-node(https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) tests in the browser using testem(https://github.com/testem/testem)? They both run on nodeJS but I can't figure out how to combine them. I was wondering if there were any libraries out there I could use or if anyone's successfully customized the two libraries to log test outputs in the browser.